# API for interacting with SVN server?

Tags: java, svn

I need to write an application that can check out an SVN revision to reference in the local filesystem. Is there an API that makes easy work of this? Other options include getting right down to the socket layer and writing the files myself or (absolutely do not want to do this, but it has to be left as a valid option ->) making calls to an external svn client on the local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) for Java. I have used both the IDE plugins and the API itself and it provides plenty of functionality for interfacing with an SVN and diffing specific files

Answer (score 1):

There are Subversion bindings or libraries for C/C++, Python, Java, Perl, .NET and I'm sure other environments I'm overlooking.

[SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) is the **first** hit on Google when searching for "subversion Java".